# Login with Facebook using codeIgniter PHP in localhost

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have done an application in my localhost for login with Facebook using PHP and codeigniter. I have created an app in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and I got the app id and secret key. But I am getting the following warning when trying to access.

> Warning
>   Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I am using wamp server and following details for Facebook app:

- Display Name --> Sample
- App Domains  --> localhost
- Site Url     --> http://localhost/fb-login-app/

I also have one config file named facebook.php with following code:

```
$config['facebook_app_id']              = 'MyAPPId';
$config['facebook_app_secret']          = 'SecretKey';
$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'signin';
$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = 'home';
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('public_profile', 'publish_actions', 'email');
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.9';
$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

I tried so many things and nothing worked. Any solution?

Comment: _“Also modified hosts file as follows --> 127.0.0.1 fb-login-app”_ – why, you are using the `localhost` domain as you said, and not `fb-login-app`

Comment: Sorry, I saw in an article. That's why tried. It is removed now.

Comment: in codeigniter where you use facebook login, i mean what is  controller name and function name? please add controller name and function name in Site Url

Comment: My controller name is Signin.php and function I have written inside public function index(). I also tried site url like this before ::   http://localhost/fb-login-app/signin/ but not working.

Comment: Try site url http://localhost/fb-login-app/signin/index/

Comment: I tried.. but this one also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
I have modified my Facebook.php config file as follows:
`

```
$config['app_id']                       = 'MyAPPID';
$config['app_secret']                   = 'SecretKey';
$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'index.php/signin';
$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] ='index.php/home';
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('email','user_location','user_birthday');
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.9';
$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

`

Reference Link : https://www.codexworld.com/facebook-login-codeigniter/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you try in online please upload the all file in any server and you can check it. It might have problem in localhost